# Is this valid JSON? Does root of a JSON stream/file have to be a single object or array?

Tags: json

Is the following valid JSON?

```
["start", 1234]
["open", 97]
```

I read the official standard twice and I wasn't able to find anything that said that this isn't valid JSON.

Comment: Have you tried parsing it as JSON? What happened?

Comment: I just tried it under node v6.2.1 with JSON.parse and it didn't work.  So I can assume that that doesn't work.   But where in the standard does it say that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. Couldn't help but research a bit. [RFC-7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) explicitly refers to [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), which says:

> A JSON value can be an object, array, number, string, true, false, or null

So basically, ECMA-404 tells us that a JSON value can be either of the above, but only a single one of them. Given your example:

```
["start", 1234]
["open", 97]
```

That'd not be considered valid JSON together, at it is not **an** array, but **two** arrays, and therefore two JSON values and not one.

Comment: I agree that the example is not a "JSON value", but where does it say that a JSON stream/file must be a JSON value?   And if it did say that, would that mean that: "9" is valid JSON?

Comment: I think that we all know empirically that a valid JSON stream/file is a single object or a single array.   I'm just not sure where in the spec it says that.

Comment: `"9"` is indeed valid JSON.

Comment: Dencker, thanks.   So then where the spec refers to a "JSON Value", it applies to both what is a value that's assigned to a property in a JSON object, as well as what the entire JSON file/stream ought to be.   That makes sense now.   But where does it say that in the spec?   I looked at it again.   I don't see it.

Comment: The second question is interesting, yet not specifically related to JSON. I think we must elevate ourself to parsing in general. A parser inherently parses a _single value_ structured in a specific way. **But hey, how about csv**? That's not a single value? Well, the RFC defines CSV as comma-separated records, delimited by a line ending. Multiple lines in a CSV is therefore valid, whereas multiple values in JSON is pretty much described as invalid. Parsers parse *units* as I see it.

Comment: So a CSV "unit" is, in my eyes, "one or more lines of comma-separated values", whereas a JSON "unit" is "one valid JSON value". The spec describes how multiple CSV records are separated, but the spec for JSON simply doesn't describe how multiple valid JSON values can be structured (other than inside other valid JSON values). So how would we parse it if the data structure is not defined?

Comment: I think it's reasonable and expected for a file format to indicate how it starts and how it ends.   There's plenty of file formats that require some kind of a prologue, for instance.   It's fine if JSON does not, but I would think it would be explicit about it.   With the CSV example, I don't believe it's documented formally as a standard.   But if it were, i would expect it to state that the file/stream can contain multiple instances of the record.

Comment: I sort of agree with you. CSV is [indeed formally documented by ietf](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180), and it also says that a valid csv document can contain multiple records. I think the general idea in specs are to describe it in a positive manner. Not the mood-kinda positive, but explaining what a format **is** and not what it **isn't**. The JSON specs doesn't explicitly tell us that `foo` isn't a valid value, but since it's not specified, we figure that it's not.

Comment: Just a side thought: A stream/file is nothing but a place to store a value in a specific format; so there is no difference between a "JSON value" and a "JSON stream", a "JSON stream" is just a.. streaming JSON value =)

Comment: Dencker, I fully understand what you're saying.   My point is, can you back up your assertion by pointing to the spec?  I know you can do so by testing it out using the JSON.parse implementation.   My issue here is with the spec.

Comment: I understand your points as well. My assertion is based on that is it not described in the spec, and since it's not described, we assume that it's not supported. I think we have to keep in mind that this format sprung out of Ecmascript, and was originally designed to be held by a variable, which inherently only holds a single value. But again, I do agree with you that the spec could be clearer on that point.

Comment: I agree with everything you're saying.   I'm just not as willing as you to defend why the spec.  It's not a subjective opinion that it's lacking a significant aspect the file format.   Thanks for your feedback.